# Bootstrap web page - centering the whole page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm setting up a responsive web page with bootstrap, I want the whole page to be centered, with equal width margins on both sides. I've applied the css class to the container div:

```
 .centered { 
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;   
    }
```

This seems to work fine on lower resolution screens but for a higher resolution laptop,
the whole page still appears aligned to the left.

How do I fix this?

Comment: It's likely centering to the middle of whatever contains it. If it's bootstrap's `container`, it will have its own margins on devices over a certain size. So, you need to make sure whatever contains it (and all elements up the hierarchy) are using 100% width of the viewport. You could define this yourself via CSS or use `container-fluid`.

I didn't submit this as an answer because I need more info on the rest of the page containing said element (a jsfiddle or plnkr would be nice) for a concrete answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using `container-fluid` : `<div class="container-fluid centered">`